# Azure webjobs queue message visibility time

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

When using an azure webjobs queue, is it possible to queue a single message with a particular visibility time (i.e. when the message becomes available on the queue for processing)?

For the sake of retrying messages that we fail to process, it would be helpful to be able to re-queue with some sort of back-off so that transient problems have a chance to resolve themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible when working with Service Bus Queues. Azure Storage Queues do NOT have this behavior. The [QueueClient ScheduleMessageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient.schedulemessageasync?view=azure-dotnet) method will allow you to do so.